# Dynamic table names in stored procedure without using EXEC

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that requires the table name where some data comes from be dynamic and supplied via a parameter.

However, because you cannot use variables in a lot of SQL statements and I do not want to have to wrap all my statements around exec statements (because it's very clunky, requiring everything to be converted to strings and additional quote marks), is there a way to do this?

So can I create a synonym on the table in my stored procedure, then use that throughout, e.g. this seems to work but I'm not sure of the consequences...

```
exec('create synonym NEILTABLE FOR '+@var1);

select * 
into dbo.temptemp 
from NEILTABLE 
where location_spatial is null;

drop synonym NEILTABLE;
```

Thanks.

Comment: No. It's Impossible to parameterize identifires in SQL without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've just tried it and updated my question as it seems to work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You've edited out the impossible part so now your code is possible... However, I still don't see how is that going to help you. Parameters in SQL are simply placeholders for data. That's why they protect you from SQL Injection - any SQL code inside a parameter would not be executed but considered as a part of the data. That's why you can't parameterize identifiders without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: whoops, sorry, I did a quick update. I thought it was too good. I'll refresh. This just seems a bit poor because it means you have to stringify all your stored procedure SQL and lose any ability to parse it or have it syntax coloured. I guess I could force the synonym to exist first on the database...

Comment: No. It means that SQL is not a programming language (it's name is standard **query** language, after all). You should not strive to have a single procedure for all your tables, but write specific procedures for each table you need.

Comment: Hello, my code is specific to single table, but some reference data may come from a different table, surely that is what a parameter is for? btw, I've updated my query and it still works.

So regardless of the merits of my approach in trying to use a stored procedure dynamically, is there anything wrong with my bit of code that I don't know?

Comment: Not with that bit specifically, but you can't use a synonym in a DDL statement (and has other limitations), so if you do anything more complex you will quickly run into roadblocks. Just a heads up.

Comment: Ok, it's only DML I'm using, specifically SELECT only

Comment: Please realize that even if this "works" it has concurrency issues all over it. If two people are executing the procedure at the same time you will get the incorrect data because the synonym changed. This is even more risky than a standard dynamic sql approach in my opinion.

Comment: Seconding Sean: if you have to use dynamic table names, then please at least use dynamic SQL in preference to creating and dropping synonyms on the fly. There are more options to consider as well: table parameters, table-valued functions, restructuring your data so table names *are* static (possibly combined with views that combine tables through `UNION`), [sharing data between procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), and last but not least solving the problem in client code (which has a far easier time constructing dynamic statements). I'd pick any of those over ad-hoc synonyms.

Comment: Re: dynamic SQL: while doubling up quotes will remain annoying, there are a few things that make life easier: `QUOTENAME` for safely escaping identifiers, `CONCAT` to chunk expressions together without casting everything and `FORMATMESSAGE` to keep strings together (the latter two from SQL Server 2012 onwards).